# IE11 Edge JavaScript Deprecated and obsolete features

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-11, msdn

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features)
said "You should use toISOString instead of the deprecated toGMTString method in new code."

However,

In [MSDN JavaScript Version Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz(v=vs.94).aspx) to check the toGMTString Method, IE11 still support this element.

I am working for IE11 Edge Mode, I should follow MSDN or Mozilla?
Thanks for help.

Comment: use feature detection - as advocated by [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Browser_Feature_Detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECMAScript](https://es5.github.io/#B.2.6) says `toGMTString` is deprecated. `toISOString` is not supported in IE8 and earlier. If you need to support IE7/IE8, use the deprecated one. If you want to be compatible with current standards, use the recommended one. "deprecated" does not mean it doesn't exist any more; it means there are reasons not to use it (including, potentially, that it won't exist for much longer). Even better, use both - see which is available and use that, for the best coverage. MDN has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Polyfill) you can use to patch up the deficiencies of older browsers.

Comment: +1 for the last statement ('use both'). Just make sure to check for the *more modern* one first, and *fall back* to the older if necessary.